# JQuery droppable having a handle drop function with additional parametes

Tags: javascript, jquery, droppable

So I understand this is how we normally call a jquery droppable:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) { ... }
})
```

Is it possible for me to write something like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui, additionalParameter) { return function(){....} }(myParameter)
});
```

Comment: As long as the value is a function reference, you can do whatever you like. So yes! You probably want to capture the event and `ui` object, so your code should be `drop: function(additionalParameter) { return function(e,ui){....} }(myParameter)`

Comment: @davin thanks, that worked like a charm :). If you could post this as an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the value is a function reference, you can do whatever you like. So yes!

You probably want to capture the event and `ui` objects, so they need to be parameters in the *returned* function. So your code would be:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
   drop: function(additionalParam){ return function(event, ui){...}; }(myParam)
});
```